# Could not load file or assembly … or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80FC3C2C

Tags: .net, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

Exception message: Could not load file or assembly System.DirectoryServices or one of its dependencies. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80FC3C2C

Exception raised from CLR SQL procedure. Exception raised from the method in the assembly where one of the classes from System.DirectoryServices is initialized and that assembly is used by the assembly with CLR procedure.

Environment:

1. MS SQL Server 2005 Std.
2. .NET framework 2.0
3. Database where assembly is created has parameter TRUSTWORTHY set to ON
4. Assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Comment: Fusion log viewer Didn't work when debugging on MS SQL server.

Comment: @NetRat: I find that hard to believe.  Did you run fuslogvw as admin?  Did you reboot after turning on logging?  Does the log contain *nothing* (it always has stuff when on)?

Comment: @Will: I didn't reboot. Hm, will try again.

Comment: @NetRat: Gotta run it as admin (right click, run as admin) elevate and then, after turning it on, reboot.  Unless you do that it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the workaround. I added the reference to the System.DirectoryServices to the assembly that is linked to the MS SQL and in the CLR procedure code create a class from this namespace. And so System.DirectoryServices assembly became visible from the class where the main code for DS is placed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was related to the owner of the database.

It happens pretty often too when you face this error.
After restore of db it might help to fix db owner in master database:

```
--Update db owner in master database
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<<DatabaseName>>] TO 
[<<LoginName>>]' 

SELECT @Command = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Command 
            , '<<DatabaseName>>', SD.Name)
            , '<<LoginName>>', SL.Name)
FROM master..sysdatabases SD 
JOIN master..syslogins SL ON  SD.SID = SL.SID
WHERE  SD.Name = DB_NAME()

PRINT @Command
EXEC(@Command)
```

If this does not help, try the following also:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[YourDatabaseName] TO [sa]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this answer is from my notes from a training class ... You have to set PERMISSION_SET to EXTERNAL_ACCESS to access the server's file system or to access another server. This would make sense since you are using System.DirectoryServices to access another server (the domain controller).

Comment: PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE allows even more access than EXTERNAL_ACCESS, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think System.DirectoryServices assembly is simply not supported inside SQL Server. SQL Server does only allow a very specific (hardcoded) list of assemblies ([SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279%28SQL.90%29.aspx), [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx)) to be used, in order to not jeopardize it's stability.

Having said that, there seems to be a way to achieve it anyway see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959367/how-to-register-system-directoryservices-for-use-in-sql-clr-user-functions) (haven't tried it).