# SQL CLR Project , Directory Services not recognized

Tags: c#, sqlclr

I created a SQL CRL project using Visual Studio 2010 that will update Active Directory direct manager attribute based on trigger on sql database.

I registered the assembly for the database

```
use [MyDatabase]
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.DirectoryServices] 
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.DirectoryServices.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE 
GO
```

I added the `System.DirectoryServices` to solution, but the problem it is not recognized in the namespace so keep getting

> The type or namespace name 'DirectoryEntry' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The target framework is 3.5 and CPU is Any

Comment: See this other SO question [How to register System.DirectoryServices for use in SQL CLR User Functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959367/how-to-register-system-directoryservices-for-use-in-sql-clr-user-functions) which explains in great detail how to do what you're trying to do. You'll need to explicitly register that additional assembly with SQL Server

Comment: I did extactly as mentioned and registered successfully but namespace is not recognized in namespace

Comment: I have created the project using visual studio 2008 and its working fine :S